# Run-Time error '340' vb 6.0, Control Array Element '3' doesn't exist

Tags: vb6

```
Dim nPicture As Integer
For n = 1 To 4
    If p_strInstrument(n, 0) = "A" Then
        nPicture = (n * 4) + 1
    Else
        nPicture = (n * 4) + 4
    End If
    'How Can i edit the line below?
    frm_Experiment.picInstrument(n).Picture = frm_Experiment.ImageListInstrument.ListImages(nPicture).Picture
Next n

p_blnInstReady = True
'Unload Me
frm_SearchInstrument.WindowState = vbMinimized
frm_SearchInstrument.Visible = False
```

Comment: Tagging a VB6 post as C# and Objective-C is a bad idea... as is dumping a load of unformatted code with no details. You've dumped nearly 600 lines of code in here... do you really expect others to work out which is the relevant code in that? Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Hi Jon, Sorry i am New and i dont know much....below as a lines of codes which need to be edits

Comment: Read the blog post - and why have you added Javascript, ASP.NET and .NET tags? There's *nothing* in the description suggesting they're relevant.

Comment: Private Sub picQuit_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

    picQuit.Picture = ImageList1.ListImages(1).Picture
    response = MsgBox("Are you sure to quit from this experiment module?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Quit Experiment?")
    If response = vbYes Then
        frm_Main.Visible = True
        Unload frm_SearchInstrument
        Unload frm_16LED
        Unload frm_16Switch
        Unload frm_DMM    >>I need to remove this from display
        Unload frm_Scope  >I need to remove this from display
        Unload frm_Experiment
    End If
End Sub

Comment: No, please don't add code in comments. Edit your question instead.

Comment: So which Tags should i put?

Comment: And without the full Form codes some people might not understand

Comment: You should leave it at just the vb6 code, unless anything else is actually relevant - in which case that should be clear from the body of the question. And you really, *really* need to reduce the amount of code. I very much doubt that you really need 600 lines of code to reproduce the problem. You also need to be much clearer in your description - it doesn't make sense at the moment. If English isn't your primary language, ask someone (in person) to help you explain your problem.

Comment: Thanks i will try and edits my question

Comment: You *still* haven't explained what you're trying to achieve, or what's going wrong at the moment. Also, please pay attention to the preview of your post - make sure it really looks like a well-written, well-formatted question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because you have an array of controls called `picInstrument`, none of which have an `Index` property that evaluates to 3.  Check the `Index` property of each control in your array, and make sure that they go from 1 to 4 as does your `For` loop.

You're better off starting with 0, and going from 0 to 3 in your `For` loop, though.

Comment: Thanks BobRodes....I actually Fix it by going from 0 to 2 because its the last two instrument i did not want to see.....

Comment: That works.  So, perhaps you can accept this as the answer, so that other folks will be able to see the solution quicker when they have the same problem.  p.s. Do your best to follow Jon Skeet's advice in future posts.  :)